# Login user in ionic2 using API

Tags: api, angular, ionic-framework, authentication, ionic2

I want to create login and register for ionic2 using angular2.
I got an api link => api/users/login

I found different links with always other ways for authentication

I got an input in home.html

```
   <ion-content>  
      <ion-list>

     <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="nameLogin"  type="text" value=""></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="passwordLogin"  type="password" value=""></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>

<div padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

ts-file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage 
{
   nameLogin: string;
  passwordLogin: string;


    static get parameters() 
    {
        return [[Http]];
    }   
    constructor(public http:Http) 
    {

    }
      login()
    {       
       var url =  api/users/login
       // this.http.post(url, this.nameLogin, this.passwordLogin)).map(res  => res.json()).subscribe((response) => 
        //{
        //    console.log("Login successful")
      //    });

    }
```

Now I want to login user with 
username: testuser and
password: User1

But how I can do authentication?

Comment: if u are using angular2-jwt,their official doc will help: https://auth0.com/blog/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/

Comment: All you need to do is send these parameters as part of your post request. The Http.post method allows you to send data parameters so you can send the username & password to your API.

Comment: I've tried that link but doesn't work for me.

Comment: `var url =  api/users/login` => url must be a string. Also please specify dns or ip of server like `var url = 'http://www.google.fr/api/users/login'`